# Error when trying to display a video in django

Tags: python, django, video

I'm trying to make a video display randomly on my homepage. A user is able to upload a video and it would be saved to a document in media/documents as well as to a dataset. I tried the code below and it keeps giving me an error,

```
Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError at /
Exception Value: 'media' is not a registered tag library. Must be one of:
admin_list
admin_modify
admin_static
admin_urls
cache
i18n
l10n
log
static
staticfiles
tz
```

I removed if `settings.DEBUG:` from urls.py and added `.url` to `{% media 'doc.document.url' %}`, however this didn't work.

**home.html**

```
{% load media %}
    {% for doc in document %}
     <video width='320' height= '240' controls>
      <source src="{% media 'doc.document.url' %}" type='video/mp4'>
      Your browser does not support the video tag.
     </video>
    {% endfor %}
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.conf import settings
...
class Document(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='NoTitle')
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    document = models.FileField(upload_to='documents/')
    uploaded_at = models.DateTimeField("date published")#(auto_now_add=True)

    creator = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path("", views.homepage, name="homepage"),
    path("myconta/", views.myconta, name="myconta"),
    path("upload/", views.model_form_upload, name="upload"),
    path("register/", views.register, name="register"),
    path('', include("django.contrib.auth.urls")),
]

#if settings.DEBUG:
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**views.py**

```
def homepage(request):
    return render(request=request, template_name="main/home.html", context={"sites": Info.objects.all})
    return render(request=request, template_name="main/home.html", context={"document": Document.objects.all})
```

**settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'main.apps.MainConfig',
]

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

**Directories**

```
MySite
 -main
   -__pycache__
   -migrations
   -static
     -images
      main.css
   -templates
      [all my html code]
    init
    admin.py
    apps.py
    forms.py
    models.py
    tests.py
    urls.py
    views.py
 -media
   -documents
 -mysite
   -pycache
    init.py
    settings.py
    urls.py
    wsgi.py
  db.sqlite3
```

Answer (score 0):

**home.html**

```
{% load media %}
    {% for doc in document %}
      <video width='320' height= '240' controls>
      <source src="{{ MEDIA_URL }} {{ doc.document.url }}" type='video/mp4'>
      Your browser does not support the video tag.
      </video>
    {% endfor %}
```

**settings.py**

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '/media/')
```

Comment: I tried your code and am still getting the same error. However I did also try it as ```{{ MEDIA_URL doc.document.url }}```. Unfortunately that didn't work either.

Comment: My ```BASE_DIR``` is currently like this, ```BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))```. I don't know if this makes a difference though.